# $http is not working to set common header in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, header

Here is the code in app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage']);
var interceptor = function() {
return {
    'request': function(config) {
        config.headers['orgName'] = 'abc';
    }
}};
app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
});
```

and after that i have all controllers.
Still i am not able to get header.
Can anyone help fast please?

Comment: You need to return the config object in the interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

From the angular documentation:

> request: interceptors get called with a http config object. The function is free to modify the config object or create a new one. The function **needs to return the config object directly, or a promise containing the config or a new config object**.

You forgot to return the config object.

```
function interceptor () {
return {
    'request': function(config) {
        return config.headers['orgName'] = 'abc';
    }
}};
```